# Определить номер текущего элемента и вывести его в span

Tags: jquery, pagination, switch

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть небольшой переключатель div блоков на jQuery. Пытаюсь сделать "пагинацию" для него, но в какой-то момент всё пошло не так.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });
    
    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
    <div class="cls1">1</div>
    <div class="cls2">2</div>
    <div class="cls3">3</div>
    <div class="cls4">4</div>
    <div class="cls5">5</div>
    <div class="cls6">6</div>
    <div class="cls7">7</div>
</div>

<div class="divs-nav">
<a id="prev">Prev</a>
<span class="divs-nav__cur">1</span>
/
<span class="divs-nav__total">7</span>
<a id="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Помогите реализовать примерно такой вид переключателей: "< Prev **2 / 7** Next >"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом для задачи

> Определить номер текущего элемента и вывести его в span

достаточно добавить строку

```
$(".divs-nav__cur").text($(".divs div:visible").index()+1);
```

Однако, для упрощения кода я бы сделал следующее:

- объединить обработчики кликов вперед/назад
- не использовал `:visible`, это несколько усложняет  код, проще использовать css-класс, например, `.current`.

```js
    $("#next,#prev").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var lastIdx = $(".divs div").length - 1;
        var cIdx = $(".divs .current").index();
                
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'next'){
           cIdx = cIdx == lastIdx  ? 0 : cIdx + 1;
        }
        else{
           cIdx = cIdx == 0 ? lastIdx : cIdx - 1;
        }
        
        $(".divs div").removeClass("current")
              .eq(cIdx)
              .addClass("current");

       $(".divs-nav__cur").text(cIdx + 1);           
    });
```

```css
.divs div { display: none; }
.current { display: block !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
    <div class="cls1 current">1</div>
    <div class="cls2">2</div>
    <div class="cls3">3</div>
    <div class="cls4">4</div>
    <div class="cls5">5</div>
    <div class="cls6">6</div>
    <div class="cls7">7</div>
</div>

<div class="divs-nav">
   <a id="prev">Prev</a>
   <span class="divs-nav__cur">1</span>
   /
   <span class="divs-nav__total">7</span>
   <a id="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Однако в реалиях проекта всё равно не срабатывает переключение. Возможно потому что в примере **a** имеет **id="next"**, а в реалиях **a** имеет **class="myclass myclass__next"**. Я пытался учесть это в вашем коде, но безуспешно.

Comment: @Idon'tknowhowithappened дак замените `$("#next, .... ").click(...)` на `$(".myclass__next, ....").click(..)`

Comment: прогнал всё на jsfiddle - работает отлично, внутри проекта переключатели не реагируют. В общем спасибо ещё раз, к коду никаких претензий, видимо какой-то конфликт внутри и даже в консоли нет ошибок.. Буду разбираться.